# Webcam JS in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

I am using jhuckaby/webcamjs jquery plugin for the webcam.

I am using the Bootstrap modal to load the webcam.

But the Adobe notification is not auto populating in the bootstrap modal.

The Notification image is:

[image]

The notification is loading when I am directly loading the camera div without modal

**JQuery**

```
 var swfURL = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jscam.swf")';
  $("#Camera").webcam({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                mode: "save",
                swffile: swfURL,
                onLoad: function () {
                    $("#SubmitPic").on("click", webcam.capture);
                },
                onTick: function () {
                },
                onSave: function () {
                    UploadPic();
                },
                onCapture: function () {
                    webcam.save(captureImageSaveURL);
                },
                debug: function () { },
            });
```

**HTML**
**Modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header model-bg">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Take Picture</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="take-photo">
                <div style="border: 4px solid #ccc; padding: 5px">
                    <div id="Camera" style="height: 240px; width: 100%;"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <center>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#fff;" id="SubmitPic" name="command" value="Capture" onclick="clickCapture();">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>@Resources.VMSResource.Capture
                            </button>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Button**

```
 <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary cam-al">
                                        <a href="#" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                            <img src="../Images/cam.png" alt="cam" style="z-index: 9999;">
                                            <span style="color: #fff;">@Resources.VMSResource.TakePhoto</span>
                                            <input type="button" id="Capture" name="command" value="Reset" class="upload">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

Please assist me in resolving the issue.

Comment: The warning dialog appears as soon as you call the `.webcam()` method. If you don't want it to appear until the modal is visible, call it when the modal fires an event to say it's ready.

Comment: Thank you, Rory.  It Worked!!!